# IntelliJ - is there an option to automatically add extra parameters to a constructor?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am adding a 3rd parameter to this constructor (the `String?` `memberId`), does anyone know how or why IntelliJ doesn't give me the option to insert this new constructor parameter automatically? The best it can do is change the type of the next parameter, or make a second constructor, which I would have thought it should be kind of obvious to IntelliJ these are probably not useful.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with IntelliJ to say whether it is possible or not (hence a comment, not an answer). But you ask why it doesn't give you the option, I'd guess it's because of the complexity of implementing the feature. Assume you have `MyConstructor(int i1, int i2)`, and you provide 3 `int` values, how would IntelliJ know where you want the new parameter to go. Does it insert it before `i1`, between `i1` and `i2`, or after `i2`?

Comment: Another potential issue is if it _were_ to add the parameter into the constructor, one may assume that any other places in the code where that constructor is called will be updated to include the new parameter too. However, IntelliJ wouldn't know what value to put into the refactored constructor call. As mentioned in the previous comment though, I don't know if it is actually possible or not - if so, these comments will be irrelevant!

Comment: I believe IntelliJ is smart enough to do it because hitting ctrl+f6 brings up a dialog to change the signature in the same way, and it will step let you choose the default value of the new param. However it will assign that value to every instance, whereas really it should let you step through them one at a time. Maybe this feature doesn't exist, I am surprised though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected feature is supported in Code Completion. `memberId` argument is supposed in completion list with first priority. Using 'Ctrl+Space' and ',' completes the arguments. This behavior is also the same for other type of functions (not only for constructors).

Note: there is no such quick fix in case of Java:

```
public class Test {
    private String s;
    private Integer n;

    Test(String s, Integer n) {
        this.s = s;
        this.n = n;
    }

    public Test foo() {
        return new Test(s); // there is no quick fox to add 'n' argument but it presents in completion
    }
}
```

FYI: There is an opposite situation when argument is added on use-site but parameter is not yet added at declaration site. Here is a ticket for supporting quick fix for that: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8478. (edited)

Comment: Thanks yes it looks like that ticket is actually exactly what I am talking about (but more succinct) :)

Comment: Actually the [KT-8478](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8478) ticket is different.

In your case you have already added parameter to method (constructor) declaration and expecting to have an available quick fix to add argument to method (constructor) usage. There is no ticket for that feature because it is already supported with Code Completion both in Kotlin and Java.

The ticket fixes the opposite problem when argument is added to method usage but there is no parameter in method declaration. That is why I added it in FYI section.